# Dynamically mirror properties to another class

Tags: swift, reflection

I'm currently working on using [Realm](https://realm.io) together with the Swift framework *[Oatmeal](http://getoatmeal.com)*. Now, both of those require model classes (Oatmeal can do automatic serialisation). My structure for a given Oatmeal model and Realm model are as follows:

```
class OatmealModel: SerializableObject {
    var id: Int = 0
    var someOtherProperty: String?
    var anotherUnknownProperty: SomeType?

    var store: RealmModel?
}

class RealmModel: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var someOtherProperty: String?
    dynamic var anotherUnknownProperty: SomeType?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

As should be clear, they both hold the same properties, but the `OatmealModel` is always the one I interact with. Aside from this, the `OatmealModel` also implements a protocol to retrieve data:

```
protocol PersistentStore {
    func save()

    func findStore()

    func all() -> [PersistentStore]

    func filter(predicate: NSPredicate) -> [PersistentStore]
}
```

These methods allow us to fetch from the Realm database and then hydrate the oatmeal model, and get only oatmeal models back. And then calling `save` will write back to realm.

So essentially, what I want to do is:

- When retrieving entities from the Realm DB and hydrating Oatmeal models, this should be done automatically. Currently, every oatmeal model has to set the `all` and `filter` (and `save`) methods separately just to replace the class name, and the properties currently have to be set manually. My plan is to somehow use reflection on both the oatmeal model and the realm model to see which properties have the same name and type, and then write them from one to the other.

Currently, I have no idea how to go about this, so any hints on how I could use reflection for this would be helpful. I assume somehow use the Mirror to extract the properties and then loop through them and see if one of the same name exists in the other?

Also, to achieve this in the end, since it'll be the models doing this to return instances of itself, is it somehow possible for a model to create an array of its own type, without explicitly writing the type? E.g `[Self]` (which doesn't work) rather than `[OatmealModel]`?

I'm fairly new to Swift, but am familiar with a few other languages and concepts, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use runtime introspection in combination with subclassing your two classes with `NSObject`, the latter allowing you to set values of given class for a given key (= variable name, `setValueForKey`). This however, is totally non-Swifty and removes any type- and runtime safety that Swift is so renowned for. You should be able to achieve what your looking for without resorting to such measures. I'm a bit uncertain what that is, though, but I can only recommend not to use runtime introspection in such a manner (if we've such a point: there's usually a better solution a few steps back).

Comment: Fortunately, the Oatmeal objects and Realm objects are both subclasses of NSObject deep down, but let's see if there's a way without runtime introspection...